# isotope overlapping images not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I hope the community can help. I know roughly what needs to be done, except i do not know how to read the code. What i have added below shows you the working filter code, with two different options that i have researched on imagesLoaded. Except when i uncomment the snippets it fixes the stacking but then fails to filter at all. I could do with some advice please.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( function() {

 // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });

//method 1 to stop stacking
// var $container = $('.isotope').imagesLoaded( function() {
//   $container.isotope({
//      itemSelector: '.element-item',
//     layoutMode: 'fitRows'
//   });
// });



  // bind filter button click
  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });


  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });

//method 2 to stop stacking
// layout Isotope again after all images have loaded
// $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
//   $container.isotope('layout');
// });



});

</script>
```

Comment: You need to make a jsfiddle. What version of isotope are you using?

Comment: I don't know how to set up a jsfiddle but i do know my version:  * Isotope PACKAGED v2.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagesloaded is not included with isotope v2 as it was with v1.5, so you need to make sure is is loaded separately. Download it [here](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js) and include on your page. Then use this setup:

```
var $container = $('.isotope');
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
$container.isotope({
itemSelector: '.element-item',
 layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that seems to have done the job. i don't think i would have ever known about it being missing in V2.